# Installing anaconda over existing python system?

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, conda

I found an old windows xp machine running Python `2.5.2`. I would like to use Anaconda instead. Can I just install Anaconda on it and do I have to uninstall Python 2.5.2? Similarly, I have a Mac system with Python `2.7.9` working with some NLT libraries and I'd like to get Anaconda running on it too. What's the best course of action to get Anaconda over an existing system that already has python?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*Simply install*.

Anaconda manages Python for you and creates the appropriate `bin` directory containing the executable and `pkgs` directory containing installed packages. All this in a directory structure named `anaconda` (or `anaconda3` if using Python 3). Additionally, it alters the search path so the Python inside the `anaconda/bin/` directory is the one used when the command `python` is issued.

On Ubuntu, it looks like this:

```
# added by Anaconda 2.3.0 installer
export PATH="/home/jim/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

By adding the new path in the beginning of `PATH` it assures the anaconda `bin/python` will be located first.

#### Warning:

> do I have to uninstall Python 2.5.2?

In general **never remove the 'original' Python unless explicitly allowed by official sources**. In many operating systems Python **is a dependency**; it **must** stay around. I can't speak for old versions of Windows but in general if you're not sure if it is needed or not **leave it**.

Removing it might *break* some completely unrelated things.

Comment: @jim-fasarakis-hilliard I already installed Python3 via Brew using the 'sandboxed' set up that installs in path `/usr/local/bin` with virtualenvs to avoid conflicts with default MacOS Python2 in `/usr/bin`. But I want to install R via Anaconda. Should I avoid Anaconda and just install R manually? Is there a 'proper' install procedure for R like there is for Python3?

Comment: Thanks for the **warning**.  I was considering this myself and it suddenly clicked what a silly idea that was after reading your warning.  Thanks!

Comment: I have an Anaconda agnostic setup. I only use pyenv with python 3.8 set globally. But I want to install Anaconda to use Spyder with PyCharm at the same time. How do I install Anaconda without it making the default python Anaconda's python or breaking my current paths? If I type "python" in my shell I do not want it to be Anaconda's python. But I want to use Anaconda's Spyder etc. I can set my own python 3.8 interpreter in Spyder myself.  What do you recommend?

Answer (score 5):

The Python installation on a Mac is not affected at all when installing Anaconda. However, Anaconda manipulates the $PATH environment variable. No need to uninstall Python.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Do not uninstall Python from our existing System. The Anaconda installer install Python **if necessary**

You can check what the anaconda packages includes: http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs

This also applies to Mac OS, from both Python 2.x or 3.x

Comment: Just installed miniconda, and it installed python 3.7.1 even though I already had python 3.7.0 installed (in `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`)